# Is "rather" shifting to become a verb?

Tags: verbs, grammaticality, adverbs

In colloquial English, I constantly run across sentences of the form:

> I rather my [noun] [verb]

A quick Google search returns tons of examples:

> - I rather my opponents don't find out.
> - I rather my fans not read this.
> - I rather my teeth froze than hurt.
> - I rather my smile with the braces on.
> - I rather my kids smoke pot than drink alcohol.

Looks like "rather" is on its way to becoming a verb, a synonym of "to prefer". When did that start? Obviously there are several steps to this process, from "I'd rather do X" via "I'd rather X" to "I rather X". But none of the dictionaries I have checked, from Hornby to Merriam-Webster to Cambridge to Wiktionary, seem to have picked up this usage just yet. So how recent is this phenomenon?

**Edit** five years later, just discovered this gem in an MMOG forum:

> I would rather the team not be hard at work to fix things. I would have rathered the team be given a realistic amount of time to put together as complete a product as possible.

So the shift is nearing completion. And going by that user's posts, we're looking at a native speaker here. However, their location is unclear from their profile. Can someone supply any data on where this usage is common or spreading now?

Comment: Good question. I rather suspect the answer is no, though it's common enough in colloquial speech.

Comment: English is full of homophones which are different parts of speech. The fact that there is a verb that sounds like "rather" and an adverb that sounds like "rather" has nothing to do with whether either is correct.

Comment: @Alan: my point is precisely that there is *no* verb that sounds like "rather"; there is not a single dictionary that lists "rather" as a verb. I thought my question was pretty clear in that regard.

Comment: Retagging as per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/72/should-we-prefer-singular-or-plural-in-tags

Comment: Do you mind changing/eliminating the example "I'd rather my kid die..." as it is particularly offensive, or could be construed as such

Comment: @mfg: good point, I was just mindlessly copy-pasting from Google. Done.

Comment: A friend of mine told me _I'd rather you didn't refer me_. It is also another case of _rather_ being used as verb, even if it's not followed by a possessive adjective.

Comment: I’ll bet you’ve never met somebody who **rathers* anything, nor has ever **rathered* in the past.  If it were truly a verb, you would have.  Verbs have inflections.  Adverbs don’t.

Comment: -1, All of the sentences quoted are quite ungrammatical, and I have never seen 'rather' used in that way in any literate document. I would say 'I would rather my opponents don't find out'. This could be shortened to 'I'd rather my opponents don't find out.' Rather is an adverb, in the same way as 'likely' in 'He will likely fail'

Comment: This phenomenon is infuriating... I have now lost all hope in humankind.

Comment: Has no one ever head of [verb phrase ellipsis (VPE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_phrase_ellipsis) before?

Answer (score 18):

In this case, I think "would" is being used as the subjunctive of "will," "will" meaning to desire. So in the case you describe, it means something akin to "wish." I admit it sounds archaic, but I'm pretty sure it's okay. I know Shakespeare uses "I would it were..." often enough. And as you set out in the question, we still use it today.

The first two sentences, as written, don't make sense. "Rather" is not a verb. I've never heard it used like one, either. I'm guessing if you've heard that it was a mistake, and they meant to say/ type "I'd rather..."

So, as far as I know "I rather my opponents don't find out" doesn't make sense. "I'd rather my opponents don't find out" does. You can insert a verb into most of the sentences if using "would" as the subjunctive of will bothers you, but it's not necessary.

Comment: If the verb is "would", isn't "rather" supposed to be in front of it? "I rather would my son was a rock star"

Comment: That's not a rule I've ever heard of...Adverbs can go before or after the verb they modify. For example: "I preferably ran for 4 miles before returning," and "I ran preferably for 4 miles before returning" both make perfect sense. Sometimes it sounds better in one position than the other, but beyond that, I don't think it matters.

Comment: @kitukwfyer: he is not talking about adverbs in general, he is talking about a particular adverb. "Rather" behaves differently from "preferably". Besides, your explanation is too far-fetched. I seriously doubt that people who say "I'd rather my son was a rock star" use the "'d" as the subjunctive of "will". Heck, from my experience, they usually have no idea what subjunctive is to begin with. They just think that "rather" means "to prefer". Note all the cases in which there is no verb at all: "I rather my fans not read this." Your explanation fails then at the latest.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood, then. My point was that "I rather would..." sounds awkward, but beyond that I don't think there's anything wrong with it...Also, just for the record, even though people don't know what the subjunctive is, that doesn't mean they don't use it. I think "I would rather my son were a rock star" is an example of this, just like "so be it"...I did fail to address the "I rather..." sentences. I've honestly never heard it and don't think it registered when I first read the question. Thanks for that. I'll edit when I get the chance.

Comment: I agree with this answer. It is most likely that *I’d rather* has evolved from what historically was the subjunctive of *will*. It doesn’t matter that modern speakers are unaware of this development. I find the *I rather...* sentences to be wrong.

Comment: Can 'would' also be seen as a form of 'to be'?

Comment: If you look at Google books, it's quite clear that in the 16th century, the expression was *I had rather* and not *I would rather*, just like it is *I had better* and not *I would better*. Without further evidence, I don't believe this evolution from the sense of "will" meaning "want".

Answer (score 9):

I'd say that rather than 'rather' being a verb here, the verb is omitted and presumed to be obvious.

Now, pedantically speaking, this may be something to frown upon, but is certainly common. And, I agree, it is jarring to hear.

Comment: Yes, pedantically speaking one should never leave words out. English teachers don't do it, and I don't [leave words out], either. It's terribly uncouth.  :)

Comment: the funny thing is that grammatically, it would make much more sense to omit the "rather" and keep the verb, because the verb carries all the meaning, while "rather" is merely an amplifier of that meaning. "I rather hot salsa" is completely ambiguous, it could mean "I rather like/love/prefer hot salsa" just as well as "I rather dislike/hate/detest hot salsa". Of course, in everyday speech, the implied meaning is always positive, but that's precisely my point: people are increasingly using "rather" as a synonym for "to prefer".

Comment: I agree. For a negative sense "rather not" is used. But, "rather" depicts a sense of implicit comparison, which the verb only use can not put across.

This is certainly not meant to be justification for that use case, just an explanation of it.

Comment: www.dictionary.com defines 'rather' with this usage and gives the part-of-speech as "idiom", which I take to mean it doesn't make grammatic sense but is used often enough to be considered correct

Comment: @Alan Hogue: True of course (and amusing post), but I'll point out that Shakespeare did it. The first example I found was Capulet, from Act 1, Scene 5 of Romeo and Juliet: "I'll to my rest." (http://shakespeare.mit.edu/romeo_juliet/romeo_juliet.1.5.html)

Answer (score 8):

In all but your first two examples, there *is* a verb - it's the contracted `would` in `I'd`. So the `rather` is modifying that `would`, which is used as the subjunctive of 'will' in the sense of 'want'.

Comment: But "would" is clearly an *auxiliary* verb here. The actual verb (would *do what*?) is obviously omitted. "I would my wife made mines" makes zero sense to me, with or without "rather". Besides, "rather" must be placed *before* the verb it modifies, not after. "I rather like it" is correct, "I like rather it" is gibberish. Similarly, "I rather would" makes sense, but "I would rather" doesn't, unless it precedes yet another verb ("I would rather do/see/prefer/know/...").

Comment: No, I don't think you're right. It's true that these days, the primary meaning of `would` is as an auxiliary. But historically that's not been its only meaning, and you can definitely find examples of uses eg in Shakespeare - [see this search](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/ss.cgi?q=%22I+would%22&mode=k) - that correspond to your "I would my wife made landmines."

Comment: "Would" is definitely not functioning as an auxiliary here. Grammatically (but not semantically) it is the main verb of the main clause. When you say "I'd rather he go" it's really "I would rather _that_ he go". Here you can clearly see that we have a main clause and a subordinate clause functioning as the direct object.

Comment: @Gregory: again, if "would" were the main verb of the main clause, "rather" would be positioned *before* it, not after. In "I rather would that he go", there is no question that "would" is the main verb, while "I would rather that he go" immediately raises the question "You would rather *what* that he go?", because "rather" cannot be placed directly before a "that" of a subordinate clause.

Comment: @RegDwight: No, there's more than one meaning of "rather", according to its position. "I rather like X" suggests a fairly high degree of liking; "I like X rather than Y" suggests a preference for one over the other. In this case it's the latter meaning that is used - "I would rather he were not here" means "I would prefer it if he were not here", hence why it goes after the verb.

Comment: @psmears: so you actually end up saying that "rather" (adverb) means "prefer" (verb), which was precisely my point to begin with.

Comment: @RegDwight: Not really... perhaps I could have been clearer: I'm suggesting that "rather" in this context means "more"; the "would" conveys the meaning of "like/want"; combining them gives "like/want more" i.e. "prefer". "I would that he had gone" means "I wish he had gone"; "I would rather he went" means "I would prefer him to go".

Comment: @psmears: but then how do you explain the examples without the *would*? At this point I really wish I had limited the question to these examples only, as pretty much everybody is completely ignoring them. ("I rather my opponents don't find out", "I rather my fans not read this", and [many, many more](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+rather+my%22).)

Comment: @RegDwight - as others have commented, these just seem wrong/ungrammatical to me (even in a colloquial context) - as if someone has misheard (or mistyped) the original phrase - or perhaps the "'d" is so slight in pronunciation that they choose not to write it. It's possible that there is some dialect in which this is acceptable, but to me (British) it just seems like a mistake (albeit perhaps a common one - perhaps akin to "could of", "would of" in place of "could have", "would have" etc.)

Comment: @psmears Is verb phrase ellipsis ungrammatical, so to speak?

Answer (score 4):

"Rather" here is functioning as an adverb. I don't understand those who say that there is no verb. This is a classic example of a fossilized, [fixed expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_expression), of which English (and most languages) have many.

As kitukwyfer stated, "would" here is the subjunctive of "will" in its older sense of "want", and the word order dates from a time when English, like German, had a stronger preference for verb-second word order, in which the finite verb is always the second phrasal element of a clause. (This can still be found in other fossilized expressions like "so do I" in which the word "I" is shifted to the end because the verb must occupy the second position.)

To sum up, every one of these expressions has not one, but *two* verbs. In this fixed expression, the so-called auxiliary is not really functioning as an auxiliary. It is the main verb, the subjunctive of its older meaning of "want," modified by the adverb "rather".

Answer (score 4):

***Edit***:
A situation similar  to that of “would rather” arises with “must away” in things like:

> *Farewell we call to hearth and hall! 
>
>    Though wind may blow and rain may fall, 
>
>    We **must away** ere break of day 
>
>    Far over wood and mountain tall.*

Just because “must away” seems to lack a verb immediately following the *must* does not make *away* function as a verb there. The actual verb is omitted, elliptically. That’s the same thing as is going on with “would rather”.  *Away* is still an adverb just as *rather* is still an adverb.  Both constructs are a bit elliptical is all.

---

This is all covered under [the OED’s sense 8 of **rather**, *adv*.](http://www.oed.com/Entry/158456). Full citations provided for senses 8e and 8f below:

> ⁠8. Sooner (as a matter of choice); more readily or willingly; with greater liking or goodwill; in preference.
>
> - a. Used to express choice between two courses of action, or preference for one outcome or event over another. Freq. with *would*.
>
>   In sentences of this type rather is placed either before the verb or clause expressing the action or event preferred, or immediately before than. For the use of *to* after *than*, see **than** *conj*. 1a.
> - b. Used to express choice between two things, people, qualities, conditions, etc. Also †***no rather***, †***more rather***.
> - c. Without *than*, in contrast to a preceding (sometimes implied) assertion. Used to indicate an alternative course of action, state of affairs, etc. Also ***the rather*** (*rare*), ***but rather***.
> - d. ***had rather***: would rather; (see **have** *v*. 21c). †Hence ***to have rather*** (*rare*): to choose or prefer‥rather.
>
>   The infinitive after *had* or *have* is sometimes preceded by *to*.
> - e. ***would rather***: would rather have or choose.
>
>   - 1557    T. North tr. A. de Guevara *Diall Princes* 96,   I woulde rather one onely day of lyfe then all the ryches of Roome.
>   - 1630    Bp. J. Hall *Occas. Medit.* §xlix,   I would rather never to haue light, then not to haue it alwayes.
>   - 1675    R. Burthogge *Cavsa Dei* 99   The Parent‥who would rather than the better part of his estate‥he could reclaim and turn him.
>   - *a*1727    W. Pattison *Poet. Wks.* (1728) II. 35   O! could I hide the Wish I fear to name! Would rather kinder Fortune guide my Flame!
>   - 1792    F. Reynolds *Notoriety* ɪɪ. 24,   I would rather he'd have can'd me than nobody.
>   - 1850    *Punch* **18** 197/2,   I would rather a good dinner than a bad one.
>   - 1862    Mrs. H. Wood *Channings* II. xvii. 262,   I would rather a nurse broke one of my children's limbs, than thus poisoned its fair young mind.
>   - 1939    P. Gallagher *My Story* 54,   I would rather her stories than my father's.
>   - 1998    M. J. Lanning *Delivering Profitable Value* ii. 52   Some smokers would rather a cigarette associated with a tough, masculine, independent cowboy who lives with his horse, riding through the rain in the desert.
> - f. In contracted form, ***I'd* (also *you'd*, etc.) *rather***: I (you, etc.) would rather.
>
>   In this form of the phrase, *would* and *had* are morphologically and semantically indistinguishable as the intended verb.
>
>   - 1601    R. Yarington *Two Lamentable Trag.* sig. C2<sup>v</sup>,   Ide rather choose to feede on carefulnesse‥Then condiscend to offer violence.
>   - 1620    I. C. *Two Merry Milke-maids* ɪᴠ. i. sig. K3<sup>v</sup>,   I'd rather you wud let it alone, vnlesse you had a finer handkercher.
>   - 1685    H. Bold & W. Bold tr. in *Latine Songs* xix. 66   I'd rather both your eyes were out.
>   - 1710    *Don Francisco Sutorioso* 17   [He] swore, She was so ugly, He'd rather with the Devil's Pug lye.
>   - 1740    S. Richardson *Pamela* I. 158   Can'st thou not stab me to the Heart? I'd rather thou wouldst, than say such another Word!
>   - 1796    F. Burney *Camilla* IV. ᴠɪɪɪ. x. 376   She thinks so well of my son, that I'd rather he'd have her than an empress.
>   - 1825    J. K. Paulding *John Bull in Amer.* xᴠ. 263   I'd rather a man would cut off my head at once, than spit in my face.
>   - 1855    E. C. Gaskell *North & South* II. iii. 32   I'd rather think yo' a fool than a knave. No offence, I hope, sir.
>   - 1876    F. H. Moore *Mistress Haselwode* II. v. 88   I'd rather a steady fire; these quick flames do burn them out by sheer fury.
>   - 1935    H. Heslop *Last Cage Down* ɪ. v. 51   We'd rather you settled amicably, if that's what you mean.
>   - 1970    A. J. P. Taylor *Let*. 2 Nov. in *Lett. to Eva* (1991) 19   I'd rather sit down over a good meal than go to the theatre.
>   - 2002    N. Roberts *Face Fire* xviii. 313   I'd rather a storm than rain. We haven't had enough storms this summer.
> - g. ***rather you* (also *him, her,* etc.) *than me*** (and variants): ‘I'm glad it's you (him, her, etc.) and not me’ (used to express relief at not being in the situation of the person referred to). Cf. **soon** *adv*. 10b.

The correct citation for the entry is:

> > rather, adv.
> >
> > Third edition, December 2008; online version December 2011. < http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/158456 >; accessed 17 February 2012. An entry for this word was first included in *New English Dictionary*, 1903.

Comment: The "must away/must to England" construction was very common two or three centuries ago, but seems to have fallen almost completely out of use. Maybe a more contemporary parallel is "got". Americans often leave off the "'ve" in "I've got to do something," resulting in "I got to ...". Little children often interpret this to mean that "got" is a verb and say "he gots to ...", but I have never heard an adult do this.

Comment: Thank heavens for the voice of authority. I'm astonished at some of the arguments going on here.

Answer (score 2):

For at least some speakers, "rather" is used as a verb. There is a page about this phenomenon on the *Yale Grammatical Diversity Project* website: "[Verbal *rather*](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/verbal-rather)", contributed by Jim Wood on March 27, 2013.

Wood mentions the use of the *-ed* suffix by some speakers, as in your "would have rathered" example, but also says there is earlier usage of *rather* as a verb without this suffix:

> According to Klippenstein (2012), *rather* first began to be used as a verb without any verbal suffixes (such as *-ed, -s*, or *-ing*). The earliest attestation is from Richard Edwards’s “Of Fortunes power” (page 25) published in 1576, as shown in (2a). Another early attestation comes from a 1614 letter written to Lord Binning by George Sinclair, the 5th Earl of Caithness, which is shown in (2b):
>
> > 2) a. I rather be borne Fortunate, then to be very wise.
> >     (1576)
> >
> > b. I rather I had bene buried heir.
> >     (1614)
>
> As discussed below, sentences like the ones in (2) are not acceptable for many speakers who use *rather* as a verb. (According to Wood (2013), web searches suggest that sentences like the ones in (2) may be acceptable for some speakers.) Verbal suffixes began to appear on rather in the 1890s.

Here are the citations for the references mentioned in the quotation:

- > Klippenstein, Rachel. 2012. The Behavior-before-Coding Principle in morphosyntactic change: evidence from verbal rather. *Extended Abstracts of the Annual Meeting of the Linguistic Society of America.*
- > Wood, Jim. 2013. Parasitic participles in the syntax of verbal rather. Lingua 137, 59-87.

The page contains an interactive map showing the acceptability of various sentences containing *rather* to speakers from different states of the USA.

Answer (score 0):

Let's be clear: "rather" is not a verb nor should it be used as such in formal English. 
The correct word is "prefer."
I don't know why so many are confused on this question in a forum like this. 
(The origins of this error are from the formulation "I would *rather have*".)

Comment: This is not a forum.

Comment: This 'answer' is mistaken on many levels.  As simchona says, this is a Q&A site (where evidence is required) rather than just another forum (where "I disagree" is valid).  "I'd rather" is not an synonym of "I prefer".  The formulation in Shakespeare and others is "I had rather": "I would rather have" is grammatical, but not the usage under discussion.  And actual usage clearly *has* progressed from "I had/would rather" to "I'd rather" to "I rather".

Comment: To add to @Tim's point, this Q&A site is also not about "formal English" as such. It is, rather, descriptive over prescriptive in many cases.

Comment: @TimLymington Surely you know no one who **rathers* anything.  It is not a verb, as that shows.

Comment: @tchrist: I would never use it myself, but the formulation does exist, as OP shows.  My guess is that teachers no longer explain the difference between *I'd rather* and *I'd prefer*, so pupils drift into ? *I rather*.

Comment: @TimLymington Where does the OP say that they’ve seen someone who **rathers* something? I have never seen *rather* inflected as a verb: **rathers*, **rathered*, **rathering*. (Nor even as a superlative: **rathest*. :) I therefore believe it is not a verb; the [OED explanation](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/58339/2085) seems perfectly sound, and sufficient to explain the phenomenon.

Comment: @tchrist: we seem to be at cross-purposes.  The OED explanation is clear and sensible; it does not, however, cover "I rather (noun)".  OP and Google both say this is widespread,so saying'it's bad grammar' though true, is insufficient unless you think English can never change. RegDwight says "it is on its way to becoming a verb"; if so, no Canute will stop it.

Comment: @TimLymington My point is that I have not seen any inflexional evidence that *rather* is on its way to being a verb, whether that’s as a productive, defective, or modal verb. Do you know of any? And the non-inflected instances seem wholly accounted for by the various subsenses under the OED’s sense 8 of **rather** *adv.* If you show me evidence of *rather* as a verb, then I’ll of course believe you; I just don’t feel I’ve seen any yet, that’s all. All examples so far provided fit comfortably within the OED’s adverbial citations.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the exact same thing, as I seemed to remember having been taught "rather" as an adverb in school, too. The increased occurrences of "rather" being used as verb brought me to this [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rather#Verb) entry (yeah, blame me for not having checked English.SE first):

```
rather (third-person singular simple present rathers, present participle rathering, simple 
past and past participle rathered)
(nonstandard or dialectal) To prefer; to prefer to.
```

So according to this (and the according quotations) it seems to be possible to be used as a verb on its on, albeit nonstandard.

Comment: This is just the sort of nonsense you get with uncurated crowd-sourcing: nothing your citation claims to be true is even vaguely correct. See the proper OED entry posted elsewhere in this answer. It is not a verb.  It is not nonstandard or dialectal. And there is no form **rathers*, either. Again, see the Real Dictionary for a Real Answer.

Comment: @tchrist See sumelic’s very interesting answer – must to my surprise, some US speakers do actually seem to be treating _rather_ as a verb (albeit a very, very strange one).

Answer (score -1):

In these examples "rather" stands for "preferably, more readily or willingly". You are, of course, correct. However, in spoken English sometimes the "'d" is lost and many people make this mistake even when writing.

Answer (score -2):

I'm a multilingual person from the Netherlands.
I think the use of 'rather' as a verb is common in Britain.
I certainly have heard the expression: "I rather you don't".
I always thought that the word 'rather' was used like 'wish' but today I changed my mind.

Speaking 5 European languages has taught me that etymology is the basis for most meanings of words and that going back usually teaches you why a certain word is used in a particular context.
This morning I decided to find the overall meaning of 'rather' (and that's how I found this page).

One of the explanations of the meaning of 'rather' is something like 'with ratio'.
It means something like 'with thought' or 'after (some/any) thought' or 'I conclude'.
Note that this meaning can be substituted for the word 'rather'.

> It's a rather obvious thing. > If you think about it it is obvious.
>
> I would rather have the green one. > After some thought I have the
> green one.
>
> I rather you be there. > I have reasoned you (should) be
> there. (since you reasoned it you have made the best possible choice
> and that explains the urging undertones of this sentence).
>
> I'd rather
> you be there. > (If you ask me,) I would reason that you (should) be
> there.

Note that British people often use 'rather' in a deliberate and slightly snobbish fashion. This can be linked to education in ye old days. If you can reason you had an education. If you had an education you had money or was in some other way an important person.

To me it seems perfectly clear that 'rather' has originally been used as a verb for reasoning.
What often happens is that the original meaning gets obscured and a word becomes overspecialized as a particular grammatical construct(s).

Think of these two sentences:

> I'd rather be at home.
>
> I'd rather you (would) be at home.

Note that there is a missing 'I' in the first sentence.
Note also that both sentences have a missing 'that'.

The fully written out sentences would be:

> I would rather that I would be at home.
>
> I would rather that you would be at home.

Et voila! 'rather' has become a verb!
'would' can be removed as it only signifies a condition, in this case the condition of having thought about it.

It's similar to the use of 'would' in: "I would say..." (If you asked me, I would say).
It's a meta position that came from reasoning (you reason about yourself) and can be left out.
Which makes 'rather' the verb.

Comment: The second *would be* in your expanded examples is ungrammatical; it should be *were* in each case. *I would* can in certain rare cases be a main verb on its own ('I would it were evening, and all well', Henry V), in which case in can take *rather* as an adverb.

Comment: This is wrong. *Rather* is never a verb.  Please [consult the OED](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/58339/2085).

Comment: I wonder if you're mishearing "I'd rather..." as "I rather...", or if you're confusing e.g. "I rather think that..." with "I'd rather think that..." (which superficially look similar but are different structures).

Comment: @tchrist - I agree this isn't conclusive evidence that "rather" is a verb. But I don't think "because the OED says so" is a terribly convincing or scientifically rigorous argument either. Dictionaries generally give very traditional-- and sometimes quite questionable-- lexical categorisations. It's quite possible that their categorisation is inadequate. (On the other hand, you do need to make the case either way. I'm not sure this answer quite does so.)

Comment: @NeilCoffey Yes, I understand that. I just find the OED’s explanation in its subsenses under sense 8 of *rather* in “would rather” being an adverb to be pretty thoroughly convincing, just as *away* must also be an adverb in “must away”. If there were evidence that *rather* is a verb, I’d expect to see inflexions like **rathers, *rathered, *rathering*, which I have never seen nor heard. If actual evidence to that effect is presented, I’d be glad to reconsider. Same with *away* in “must away”. Elliptical constructs like these may become verbs with time, but I don’t yet see evidence of such.

Comment: OK, I do broadly agree with the actual argument, but the thing that matters is the argument, not that it's mentioned in the OED. With the slight proviso that you do of course find defective verbs in general, and arguably in a transitional case is where you might expect them to occur. And you get cases-- possibly transitional-- such as "I'd rather that (than...)".