# "Would rather [infinitive1] than [infinitive2]" vs. "would rather that [subjunctive]""

Tags: meaning, differences, adverbs, subjunctive-mood, auxiliary-verbs

I am aware of sentences like

> Beth **would rather** study at the library **than** go to parties.

There is another type of using *rather that*:

> 1. She **would rather that** the plane leave early in the morning.
> 2. My parents **would rather** that I drive slowly.

What does this indicate in above sentences in terms of meaning?

Comment: For both of your examples, there's an implied "than". "She would rather that the plane leave early in the morning than later in the day." "My parents would rather that I drive slowly than fast."

Comment: Related: [Is “rather” shifting to become a verb?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/688/is-rather-shifting-to-become-a-verb)

Answer (score 2):

It's like to *prefer*.

For example, with your sentences:

> She would prefer that the plane leave early in the morning.
>
> My parents would prefer that I drive slowly.

*Rather* isn't a verb, so it's not grammatically correct. But, it's used anyway.

Hope this helped!

Comment: See related question: [Is "rather" shifting to become a verb?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/688/18655)

Answer (score 1):

Your first example ("would rather study") and the other two ("would rather that") are basically the same thing.

When you use the original "would rather + Verb," notice that the Subject of your sentence and the doer of the action have to be the same:

Ex. **Beth** would rather **study**

But if you wanna flexibly talk about a different person doing the action, you need to use another structure. And this is where "would rather that" comes in.

Ex. **My parents** would rather that **I**...

**I**'d rather that **you**...

---

Also, normally we would use the Past Tense of the Verb when we use the "would rather that S + V" structure.

Ex. My parents would rather that I **drove** slowly.

Although we use the Past tense, the meaning isn't Past but is still Present.

Ex. I'd rather you **didn't** tell her.

I'd rather he **moved** to another school.

---

I suppose though, about Present Tense Verbs in "would rather that S + V," that the expression is evolving - like what was previously mentioned.